# I want to add a new method in angular object, but i use @types/angular, how can I extends the angular.d.ts?

Tags: typescript

For example, I want addd a registerController method in angular, and I will get
`Property 'registerController ' does not exist on type 'IAngularStatic'`

I solve this by creating a *.d.ts with

```js
import * as angular from 'angular';

declare module 'angular' {
  interface IAngularStatic {
    registerController : any;
  }
}
```

but why should i use `import * as angular from 'angular'` and `///<reference types="angular">` is not work

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own interface and extend `IAngularStatic` like this:

```
import {IAngularStatic} from "angular";

export interface ExtendedAngularStatic extends IAngularStatic {
  registerController: any;
}
```

and use `ExtendedAngularStatic` instead.